# Powershell to update the heartbeat to cloudwatch

Tags: powershell, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a function to update the heartbeat of an server to cloudwatch. But from the below function, This function is not breaking.. I am sure i have done some mistakes.. But i am very new to powershell can you please help to correct it.

```
function Get-spooler{
$INSTANCE_ID=$(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
$service=Get-Service -Name Spooler 
write-host $INSTANCE_ID
write-host $service
write-host $service.Status
while($service.Status -eq 'Running')
{
aws --region ap-southeast-1 cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name Test13 --value 1 --namespace ssm  --dimensions InstanceId=$INSTANCE_ID
if ($service.Status -eq 'Stopped')
{
aws --region ap-southeast-1 cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name Test13 --value 0 --namespace ssm  --dimensions InstanceId=$INSTANCE_ID
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

$service stores a static object at the time you assigned it. So if the service was running when `$service=Get-Service -Name Spooler` $service.status will always equal 'Running'.

Try: `while((Get-Service -Name Spooler).Status -eq 'Running')`

Comment: I tried below it work.. thank you for checking... ```code
function Get-spooler{

$service=Get-Service -Name Spooler 
write-host $INSTANCE_ID
write-host $service
write-host $service.Status
if($service.Status -eq 'Running')
{
aws --region ap-southeast-1 cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name Spooler_Service --value 1 --namespace services  --dimensions InstanceId=i-09c6f94b869466e03
}
else{
aws --region ap-southeast-1 cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name Spooler_Service --value 0 --namespace services  --dimensions InstanceId=i-09c6f94b869466e03
}
}```